# Mysql - Select, store in var, select in same query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to understand how to do this. Not much help found.

I have two tables.
First table:

```
  CREATE TABLE `first` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',     
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Second table:

```
CREATE TABLE `second` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `foo` varchar(3) NOT NULL ,
  `bar` varchar(255) NOT NULL )
```

Id in both tables is same value, they are related that way.
I have to fetch some entries, for example with parent_id = '0' and to check if those entries have children. If they has I should get their ids too.

It could be done easily with little php and two queries but I would like to do it better. I tried something like:

```
SELECT `first`.*, `second`.*, children.*
FROM `first`
JOIN `second` ON `second`.id = `first`.id 
INNER JOIN( SELECT 
            // Something
            )AS children ON children.id = `second`.id
WHERE `first`.parent_id = '0'
GROUP BY `first`.id, `second`.la
```

But I did not make it.
How could I Select those result and their children in same query? Thanks!

EDIT
First:

```
-------------------------------------------------
| id       |  parent_id     |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1        |  0             |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2        |  1             |
--------------------------------------------------
| 3        |  2             |
--------------------------------------------------
| 4        |  1             |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Second table:

```
    -------------------------------------------------
    | id       |  foo           |  name
    --------------------------------------------------
    | 1        |  asd           |  apple
    --------------------------------------------------
    | 2        |  asd           |  banana
    --------------------------------------------------
    | 3        |  gsf           |  orange
    --------------------------------------------------
    | 4        |  gre           |  potato
    --------------------------------------------------
```

Desired Result would be to get row where id is 1 (joined both tables) and all ids of rows witch have parent_id 1.

Thanks!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: look into GROUP_CONCAT, no subquery needed

Comment: I edited as suggested. Thanks for advice. I am reading about GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: What if the children have children etc?

Comment: Yes children can have children. For my current problem I do not need to fetch childrens children. I just have to get info if current entry/row have children.